# view engine in nestjs fastify

Tags: typescript, nestjs, fastify

I am trying to implement `ejs` in nestjs fastify microservice. I have an issue with `setViewEngine`.

```
app.setViewEngine({
    engine: { ejs },
    templates: join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'views'),
  });
```

this is how i set view engine and i have `ejs` file in `src/views` folder, but it does not generate in dist folder. could you help with it?

I also tried to write it in such manner

```
  app.setViewEngine({
    engine: { ejs },
    templates: '../views',
  });
```

but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

templates path is error, u should remove 'src'

```
app.setViewEngine({
    engine: {
      ejs,
    },
    templates: join(__dirname, '..', 'views'),
  });
```

Comment: Okay but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the directory structure?

Comment: can't attach image here

Comment: btw i fixed it by copying views folder into dist whilde prebuilding. but i want better solution if there is